# Python loop through every element and delete nth element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having trouble figuring out how to loop through an array of arrays and delete the nth element. Ie. the first loop would keep everything but delete the first element, the second loop would keep everything but delete the second element, etc. Basically turn my hardcoding section into a loop

```
x1 = np.array([1,2,4,6])
y1 = np.array([2,4,6,3])
x2 = np.array([2,4,2,7])
y2 = np.array([2,5,3,4])
x3 = np.array([3,5,4,3])
y3 = np.array([2,6,1,2])
x4 = np.array([6,6,4,7])
y4 = np.array([8,9,8,4])

xs = np.array([x1,x2,x3,x4])
ys = np.array([y1,y2,y3,x4])

linear_r2 = []
quadratic_r2 = []

def linear_func(x, a, b):
    return (a * x) + b

def fit_r2(ydata, yfit):
    residuals = ydata - yfit 
    ss_res = np.sum(residuals**2)
    ss_tot = np.sum((ydata - np.mean(ydata))**2)
    r2 = 1 - (ss_res / ss_tot)
    return r2

#hardcoding
xs_1 = xs[:, 1:]
ys_1 = ys[:, 1:]
xdata = xs_1[0,:]
ydata = ys_1[0,:]
popt, _ = curve_fit(linear_func, xdata, ydata)
yfit = linear_func(xdata, *popt)
linear_1 = fit_r2(ydata,yfit)
linear_r2.append(linear_1)

xs_2 = np.delete(xs,1,axis = 1)
ys_2 = np.delete(ys,1,axis = 1)
xdata = xs_2[0,:]
ydata = ys_2[0,:]
popt, _ = curve_fit(linear_func, xdata, ydata)
yfit = linear_func(xdata, *popt)
linear_2 = fit_r2(ydata,yfit)
linear_r2.append(linear_2)
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you provided?

Comment: xs_1 = np.delete(xs,0,axis = 1) will delete only the first element. not sure how to get it to iterate every element after that. eg. xs_1 = np.delete(xs,1,axis = 1), xs_1 = np.delete(xs,2,axis = 1)... so on

Comment: There's no x3 and x4 in the code you provided.

Comment: Oop. Just added them

Comment: It is deleting the first element. Try printing `xs_1` and `ys_1`.

Comment: Right, but how would I make it so it would iterate through the other elements? First loop deletes first element, the second loop deletes the second element, and so on

Comment: What is the end result you are expecting? Since, going over the loops will eventually delete everything.

Comment: Better to think about what you want to keep.

Comment: I just added some more background, but I'd like to loop each iteration and apply the two functions. I've found a way to hardcode it but I'd like to make it into a loop

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this to delete a element in a double array.

```
arr = [[1,0,0],
       [0,1,0],
       [0,0,1]]
for position in range(len(arr)):
    arr[position].pop(position)
```